# Eclipse error occurred during: "Computing size" on Mac?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I've Installed `Eclipse` on Fresh `Mac 10.9.2`

My problem is when I try to install `Google ADT Plugin`

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

I got this error after 2 minutes

```
An internal error occurred during: "Computing size".
The profile is currently in use.
```

And the plugin installation breaks!

I've tried to remove the plugin from plugins list, and also tried to restart Eclipse. I could't find a solution on Google!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have to install `Eclipse` on Mac driver not `exFat` Driver

I moved Eclipse on Original Mac driver and its worked fine .

Many Thanks to @elieNajem for this advice

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Ninja Developers answer I've fixed the issue by formatting my USB drive as a Mac journaled partition and then moved eclipse back to it. Now it works fine. So for those who are installing to USB or external drives make sure your drive is formatted as Mac drive.